# JavaScript: How to convert any number in any number system to the browser's current locale

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, localization

I am working on an application that takes numbers with/without decimals from the users and converts them to the browser's locale number system with decimals.

Sometimes the user can type in numbers that are in another country's number system than the user's browser locale.
My application must convert those numbers to the user's browser locale number system.

1. How to convert any number in any number system to the browser's current locale?

OR

2. How to identify the locale of a given decimal number/string in javascript or Angular typescript?

Example:
number = "10,000.00";
`identifyLocal(number); // should return 'en-IN'`

number = "10.000,00";
`identifyLocal(number); //should return 'de' (German Deutsch).`

I've tried `number.toLocaleString()`. But this doesn't handle numbers that are already in another country's number system.

Thank you.

Comment: How would you recognise it as a human being? :-) If you can recognise each locale based on some rules, then surely those rules can be encoded (I'm totally unaware if such rules already exist). In the mean time, maybe you will need to resort to request your users to input the number in a predefined locale or, at the very minimum, at the locale they have their browser configured with (basically, give yourself a know locale before dealing with the data).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. From just the text of a number, the patterns used for numbers across the world are ambiguous and there is not enough information to determine locale. In your example, the number that you say should yield German is perfectly good in several other locales. You will need to have some other information to determine locale.

Assuming this is a web application, it's best to simply assume that the browser's locale is the locale of the data that the user is entering. A more advanced application might provide a separate locale setting for the user to choose for entering and displaying data (usually a setting in that user's application profile).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by doing this: There are 4 widely used number systems. 1) Comma and dot (Example: 10,000.00) 2) Dots and comma (Example: 10.000,00) 3) Space and dot (Example: 1 000.00) 4) Space and comma (Example: 1 000,00). I wrote 4 regex patterns to check into which of these number systems the entered number belongs to. Once I know which number system the entered number belongs to, I just remove the respective thousand separator, use parseFloat() and do Intl.NumberFormat(). So far it has been working fine. :)